# using repo other then pypi with pip

Tags: python, pip, ansible, openstack

I am having trouble understanding how pip works in a specific environment. The thing is that I am trying to install OpenStack using ansible-openstack deployment method. It provides playbooks to prepare the complete environment and install all components. Deployment fails at the step when python modules should be installed from a private repo (it is being built during previous deployment steps). This repo is nothing else as nginx server exposing directories with python wheels via http protocol. When OpenStack nodes are reaching over to this repo with pip in order to install packages, they seem not to find any of the packages that satisfy their constraints (I am not posting the whole command using the requirement file, but required versions are there). Each node has similarly looking HOME/./pip/pip.conf:

```
    [global]
    no-index = true
    pre = True
    timeout = 120
    trusted-host =
            172.21.51.152

    [install]
    upgrade = True
    find-links =
            http://172.21.51.152:8181/os-releases/14.0.7/
```

where 172.21.51.152 is that repo that is supposed to replace PyPI.

When playbook tasks that should install packages are running they all fail with similar error:

root@control1-galera-container-434df170:~# pip install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQL-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MySQL-python

even though the file is there and I can wget it from the URL where the file is located.

```
    ls /var/www/repo/os-releases/14.0.7/ | grep -i mysql_python
    mysql_python-1.2.5-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I checked with tcpdump what kind of request pip is sending when "pip install" command is used. It sends a GET get to http://172.21.51.152:8181/os-releases/14.0.7/ where all wheel files are. Server replies with the index.html file:

```
    <html>\r\n
    <head><title>Index of /</title></head>\r\n
    <body bgcolor="white">\r\n
    <h1>Index of /</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>\r\n
    <a href="links/">links/</a>                                             
    <a href="openstackgit/">openstackgit/</a>                                      
    <a href="os-releases/">os-releases/</a>                                       
    <a href="pkg-cache/">pkg-cache/</a>                                         
    <a href="pools/">pools/</a>                                             
    <a href="venvs/">venvs/</a>                                             
    </pre><hr></body>\r\n
    </html>\r\n
```

After getting this reply pip seems to be satisfied with the outcome and decides that the package it was looking for is not there. I am trying to figure out if that is expected behaviour and there is something wrong with that repo or if pip is being launched with insufficient configuration that doesn't allow it to perform the search.

I tried to delete the pip.conf altogether and pip worked normally just downloading files from PyPI. What am I missing here in order to make it work from the private repository?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: If you are running into this problem using `pip`, I see no reason to tag the question as Ansible (nor OpenStack). Is there any difference when you use Ansible modules?

Comment: From my opinion it makes sense to tag this question as Ansible as well, since this could draw attention of someone familiar with ansible-openstack project. At least that's my understanding of the purpose of question tagging.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this question in OpenStack Operators mailing list. Was an issue of nginx server and not working autoindex. After fixing autoindes the complete directory index started to show up which enabled pip to download and install packages.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, here's the ML post Danil mentioned: http://lists.openstack.org/pipermail/openstack-operators/2017-February/012695.html

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had the very same symptom Danil described:

```
root@control1-galera-container-434df170:~# pip install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQL-python (from versions: ) 
No matching distribution found for MySQL-python
```

The root cause in my case was a (restrictive) `umask` setting of `077`.

```
# root@controller1
$ umask  # octal
0077
$ umask -S  # symbolic
u=rwx,g=,o=
```

The default seems to be `022` (symbolic: `u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx`), details at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask

This umask of 077 affects the nginx config files (which, for example, set the 
'autoindex' behavior, which is needed to serve the python wheels):

```
# root@controller1-repo-container-e0445a8f
$ cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/
$ ll openstack-slushee.vhost
-rw------- 1 root root [...] openstack-slushee.vhost
```

If also affects the python packages:

```
# root@controller1-repo-container-e0445a8f
$ cd /var/www/repo/pools/ubuntu-16.04-x86_64/mysql_python/
$ ll mysql_python-1.2.5-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl 
-rw------- 1 nginx root [...] mysql_python-1.2.5-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
```

And these python packages get requested from the other containers in an openstack-ansible setup:

```
# root@controller1-galera-container-564eedea
$ cat .pip/pip.conf 
[...]
[install]
upgrade = True
find-links =
    http://172.29.236.11:8181/os-releases/15.1.2/ubuntu-16.04-x86_64/
```

And ultimately, it affects the file which specifies the python package versions:

```
# root@controller1-repo-container-e0445a8f
$ cd /var/www/repo/os-releases/15.1.2/ubuntu-16.04-x86_64/
$ ll requirements_absolute_requirements.txt
-rw------- 1 root root [...] requirements_absolute_requirements.txt
```

You will notice that nginx complains a lot in its error log:

```
# root@controller1-repo-container-e0445a8f
$ grep -i error /var/log/nginx/openstack-slushee.error.log | grep -i mysql
2017/07/03 10:30:34 [error] 17458\#17458: *642 open() 
"/var/www/repo/os-releases/15.1.2/ubuntu-16.04-x86_64/
mysql_python-1.2.5-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl" failed 
(13: Permission denied), client: 172.29.236.11, 
server: openstack-slushee, 
request: "GET /os-releases/15.1.2/ubuntu-16.04-x86_64/
mysql_python-1.2.5-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl HTTP/1.1", 
host: "172.29.236.11:8181"
```

Long story short, set the umask to a less restrictive mode before starting openstack-ansible:

```
$ umask 0022
```

Side notes:

- here's the discussion where I want to figure out how to handle umask in openstack-ansible: http://lists.openstack.org/pipermail/openstack-operators/2017-July/013892.html
- this question might have been better suited at https://ask.openstack.org/en/questions/